# Visual studio 2015 closed when re-run SSIS pack

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed visual studio 2015 and there is a really simple action that I can not make,
When I rerun (Ctr+Shift+F5) SSIS package (re-run, not run), it causes visual studio to throw this error:

[image]

I do not know if this is related, but the SSIS project is on the sql server 2014.

This is a routine operation that worked without problems at visual studio 2013.

Comment: Is VS2015 fully patched and up-to-date? does this happen with multiple packages, or just one? Can you build a trivial package (say, one that executes a `SELECT GETDATE()` statement only), and confirm that this happens with that?